# how to set mediaelement.js startVolume in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

I have the mejs 2.9.1 wordpress plugin installed, but cannot find any way to adjust the startVolume on (mp4, wmv, etc.) vid playback. The various .js files all show startVolume="0.8" but changes there have no effect; also no effect when using a startVolume property on the WP shortcode call. Seems like this should be easy. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

you can change the startVolume: 0.8, to something like startVolume: 0.5, Worked for me